# Does anyone know of any standards for the classification of software?

Tags: classification, portfolio

I have, of course, tried Google/Bing and have found one or two classifications for specific industries, but nothing general.
The sort of thing I'm looking for is:
General Office Tools -> Wordprocessing -> Word
Utilities -> File Management -> Compression -> Winzip

Waht I am after is a Standar that has been issued by some organization, or is used my a number of different parties - not just a classification a single org is using.

Answer (score 1):

Sourceforge has a [software map](http://sourceforge.net/softwaremap/).

Comment: At least this is comprehensive - but has many odd classifications.  (e.g. Word Processing is under Text Editors, not Office/Business). The structure looks like it grew organically rather than planned - and is certainly not a standard.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a list on [the Wikipedia article for Software Application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_software#Application_software_classification).

Comment: I saw this, but this isn't a well thought out list and certainly isn't a standard.

Answer (score 1):

UNSPSC or eClass are two competing standards for taxonomy. (Software is just a sub category)
http://www.unspsc.org
http://www.eclasscontent.com

Answer (score 0):

[sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/) has a taxonomy (categories) that projects are filed under.

Answer (score 0):

[SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net) calls its categories "Trove categories", which suggests that they are not the only ones using it, but I could find [little to no information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trove_Categorization) about this system.

Answer (score 0):

Also not an official standard, but *possibly* more consistently applied, is dmoz's [software category](http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Software/).